# customize system launchagent arguments in el capitan

Tags: macos, launchd, sip

Is there any way to work around the inability to customize launchagent plists in El Capitan *without* completely disabling system integrity protection?

Specifically, I was sad to find that my ssh-agent timeout had been removed, and horrified that I couldn't put it back. I see other q&a on how to reboot in recovery mode and disable SIP, but that seems a bit drastic... is there some other workaround?

I don't have great knowledge around launchctl as a whole; is there a way to set a `-t` option some other way than editing `/System/Library/LaunchAgents/org.openbsd.ssh-agent.plist`?

Can I disable the system-configured agent and set it up under `~/Library/LaunchAgents`? Would that lose any functionality compared to the system agent?

Comment: Why don't you just disable SIP, apply all necessary adjustments and reenable SIP afterwards again?

Comment: I'm hoping to avoid needing multiple reboots to and from recovery mode just to change the default ssh-agent timeout. Obviously that is a solution... but it has a strong "theres _gotta_ be a better way to do this" smell to it.